# ploting multi dimentional data in ggplot in r with several dataframes and mixing bars/points

Tags: r, multidimensional-array, ggplot2

I would like to plot four-dimensional data in ggplot2 in the form of bars and points. The dimensions are country, year, index and variables, for each, I have a observe value which I would like to represent on the graph. 
I basically want to split my database into two based on the year, the oldest observations get represented by bars (per country, index and variable), and overlay the most recent data as points (again per country, index and variable). I need support to add the points (i.e recent data) in ggplot2.

Graphically I would like the get the following graph, where I would like to add the circle (which I added manually). This is the final graph I would like to get

[image]

## Illustration with a reproducible example

### creating the data

```
library(dplyr)
country<-c('A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B','B','B','B','B','C','C','C','C','C','C','C','C')
year<-c('2000','2000','2000','2000',"2005","2005","2005","2005","2010","2010","2010","2010","2002","2002","2002","2002","2008","2008","2008","2008")

index<-c("1","2","1","2","1","2","1","2","1","2","1","2","1","2","1","2","1","2","1","2")

variable<-c("var1", "var1","var2", "var2","var1", "var1","var2", "var2","var1", "var1","var2", "var2","var1", "var1","var2", "var2","var1", "var1","var2", "var2")

value<-runif(20)

data<-as.data.frame(cbind(country,year,index,variable,value))
data$ct_year<-paste0(data$country,data$year)
data$value<-as.numeric(data$value)
data$ct_year<-paste0(data$country,data$year) # this is used to subset between old and recent data
```

### creating the subdatset

dataset 1 contains for each country the data with the oldest data = this data will appear as bars
dataset 2 contains if available the most recent data = this is the data that I would like to appear as a point on the top of my graph.

```
sel<-c("A2000","B2005","C2002")
sel2<-c("B2010","C2008")
data1<-filter(data, ct_year %in% sel)
data2<-filter(data, ct_year %in% sel2)
```

### creating the base graph

This the the code that leads to base graph that is used in the picture above:

```
p<-ggplot(data1,aes(country, value ,fill=variable, alpha = index )) + 
            geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge" )
```

### the issue I need to solve :

Now I would like to add the values that are stored in data2 as points on the top of my base graph. (in other terms I would like for each country to superpose as a point value of recent years of the different variables split by index). Note that country A does not have any data in data2 so only country B and C will have points appearing on the graph.

Any leads on how I could do this?

A great thanks for your support!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the following.

```
p + geom_point(data = data2, 
               aes(x = country, 
                   y = value, 
                   col = variable, 
                   shape = index), 
               size = 5, 
               stroke = 2, 
               position = position_dodge(width = 0.9),
               inherit.aes = FALSE) +
    scale_color_manual(values = c(var1 = "black",
                                  var2 = "black")) +
    scale_shape_manual(values = c(21, 21)) +
    guides(col = "none",
           shape = "none")
```

[image]

The plot differs from what you have posted because you use `value<-runif(20)` without setting a seed. For this particular example I used `set.seed(1)`.

Comment: **Thanks a million** @markus This works! it took me a while to fully understand the code, but now i got it, and the i guess the major trick was  inherit.aes = FALSE. And yes, i forgot the seed, sorry about that!

Comment: @CatherinePfeifer glad I could help. Sorry for letting you alone with the code and don't worry about the seed, I just wanted to mention the reason for the different plots. Regards.